# Git репозиторий в репозитории

Tags: git, git-репозиторий

Ситуация такая: есть проект, который отслеживается при помощи `git`, назовем его основной проект. В этот проект был склонирован удаленный репозиторий, назовем его модуль, без использования `git submodule`.

Теперь после клонирования основного проекта на другую машину папка с модулем оказывается пустой.

Как убрать из модуля его версионный контроль и добавить его в индекс основного проекта?

Comment: @zsiteru, вероятнее всего, вам нужно использовать менеджер зависимостей (для каждого языка - свой, для PHP это [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)), который избавит вас от подобных проблем вообще в принципе.

Описанная проблема скорее всего решится через удаление папки .git во **вложенном** репозитории, но, опять же, это неверный подход.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd module
rm -rf .git
git add .
git commit -m 'добавляем исходники удалённого репозитория, модуля'
```

Наверное, не стоит упоминать, что делать так не стоит, а что нужно научиться пользоваться git submodule?

Comment: Спасибо!

Еще одно действие пришлось совершить, удалить из версионного контроля каталог родитель module.

git rm -r --cached module_parent/

не знаю на сколько это правильно но только после этого папку module получилось добавить в репозиторий.

Теперь только submodule :)